# Why is Jquery parseXML not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I am new to xml and I am trying to search through a xml file using JQuery `parseXML()`. I made the code below to search for the `<name>` tags in the xml file and output each `name` it's value.

When I run the code I get these 2 errors:

```
  syntaxisfout         
  index.html:1:1

  Error: Invalid XML: test.xml    
  jquery.min.js:2:1820
```

I used this tutorial: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

This is the xml file Structure I use:

```
<store>
  <product>
      <name>product name</name>
      <price>price</price>
      <platform>platform</platform>
  </product>
</store>
```

This is the JQuery code I use:

```
xmlDoc = $.parseXML( 'test.xml' ); //path to xml file
$xml = $( xmlDoc );
$name = $xml.find( "name" );

$(document).each(function(){
    $('body').append('<p>'+ name + '</p>');
});
```

Can somebody tell what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You're completely misunderstanding what `parseXML` does.  Read the docs.  You need AJAX.

Comment: @SLaks why does it works here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

Comment: Read what the parameter is supposed to be.

Comment: Because they are using a full XML string... not an XML file name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are using a filename as your xml parameter. There is no facility within `$.parseXML` to parse a file. It parses an XML string. If you need to load XML from a separate file you will need to ajax it in or otherwise load the filecontents into a js variable:

```
xmlStr = '<store>'
 + ' <product>'
 + '    <name>product name</name>'
 + '     <price>price</price>'
 + '     <platform>platform</platform>'
 + ' </product>'
 + '</store>';

xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xmlStr);
$xml = $(xml);
// do stuff
```

With ajax:

```
$.ajax({
     url: 'url/for/text.xml',
     dataType: 'xml'
}).done(function (xmlDoc) {
    $xml = $(xmlDoc);
    // do stuff
});
```

Comment: One more question: Can I use `$name = $xml.find( "name" );` in your ajax example? and SO if I understand It right `parseXML` is to work with xml things in a variable?

Comment: Yes, and yes. Read the documentation (carefully this time) for [`jQuery.parseXML`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) and [`jQuery.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).